# How can I send sensor data to android phone via bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, sensors

I have a DHT11 temperature and humidity sensor and raspberry pi 3. I want the sensor reading to send to phone.

Answer (score 0):

DHT11 sensor is not having any predefined Android/Android things library. Check on below link which might give you an idea to work with other sensors.

https://dzone.com/articles/iot-android-things-and-the-cloud

Answer (score 0):

Long lime ago I was used [HC 06](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Components/RF/BLUETOOTH-SERIAL-HC-06/resources/hc06.pdf)
Rs232 Bluetooth adapter for similar task. It was cheap and it works.

Also look at [esp8266](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266) cheap and easy to use wifi integrated micro computer. This one can be replacement for raspberry pi in many cases.